# How is PCR duplication rate computed in scATAC-seq?

Tags: single-cell, atac-seq, pcr, duplications

Reading Cusanovich et al. (2015) I encountered the sentence:

> We mixed pairs of cell lines (HEK293T or HL-60 versus GM12878), performed combinatorial cellular indexing, and sequenced the resulting libraries to saturation (65% duplicate rate).

How is PCR duplication rate computed?

1. Cusanovich, D. A. et al. [Multiplex single-cell profiling of chromatin accessibility by combinatorial cellular indexing.](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/348/6237/910) Science 348, 910–914 (2015).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the [supplementary methods page 3](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2015/05/06/science.aab1601.DC1/Cusanovich-SM.pdf).

> Finally, all fragments in the same library with duplicate start and
>   end coordinates were removed using Picard